# Github Action step to extract .zip file?

Tags: github-actions, unzip

Is there a way to extract the contents of a .zip file as part of a Github Action with a Windows runner?

I can't seem to find a reference for things like renaming files, unzipping/zipping, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GitHub Actions just provides you with an operating system (Windows in your case), so the question is in fact, how would you do it in Windows command line. Once you know how to do this, you can do it on GitHub Actions.

GitHub Actions documentation provides a [list of pre-installed software](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/specifications-for-github-hosted-runners#supported-software) on the runners, and more particularly, the [Tools section on the Windows Server 2019 runner](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#tools) - specifies that 7zip is installed.

So, it should be a matter of just running `7z x archive.zip` in your step, or whatever the command you need.

```
steps:
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Extract some files
  run: 7z x archive.zip

# ...
```

If I were you, I would install 7zip locally, in order to figure out exactly how its CLI works, so you can just paste it later in a GitHub Action configuration file.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to get headed in the right direction. Thank you for the sample toO!

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to find a reference for things like renaming files, unzipping/zipping, etc.

Since you're using Windows, you can do everything you asked for using the built-in PowerShell. For working with .zip files, you would use [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) to open zip files and [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive) to create zip files. [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) is used to rename files and folders.

Comment: This doesn't work for servers that don't have these commands available - i.e., older versions of Windows and Powershell.